# jQuery mobile and button event and variable storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am new to mobile development and have done a little work using jQuery mobile from a tutorial I had from miamicoder.com. My challenge now is, I have two buttons on a page, I want to know the one the user taps or touches or clicks and store the value in an external .js file so I can use it to load corresponding pages at the appropriate time.  The two buttons are calling the same page and that page, scratchcard.html after verifying the scratchcard pin is supposed to load a page based on the button tapped, or touched or clicked.

I will be very glad if I can get sample code and explanation as how it is done. Below is the html5 jQuery mobile code:

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content mc-text-center"><!-- start of main content -->
    <h3 class="mc-text-center">Where Do You Want To Go Today?</h3>
    <img src="images/mantakingexams.png" alt="Man Taking Exams" />
    <p class="mc-top-margin-1-5"><b>Are you a JHS Student?</b></p>
    <a href="scratchcard.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a" id="beceButton">BECE</a>
    <p class="mc-top-margin-1-5"><b>Are you a SHS Student?</b></p>
    <a href="scratchcard.html" data-role="button" data-theme="a" id="wasceButton">WASCE</a>
</div><!-- end of main content -->
```

Comment: after loading scratchcard.html you want to load another page based on button clicked? or you want to add elements into scratchcard.html based on button clicked?

Comment: Exactly so Omar. The current page where the buttons are is called examtype.html. Now, if you select the type, I want to verify if you have a pin to do that exam using the scratccard.html. If your pin is correct, then an exam list is presented to you based on the  button selected on the examtype.html page earlier on, which is BECE or WASCE. Thank you.

Comment: so you'll navigate from exametype to scratchcard and back to examtype.

Comment: Omar, from examtype to scratchcard, and from scratchcard to either beceexamlist or wasceexamlist depending upon the button tapped or touched or clicked at examtype. At examtype, if the user tapped BECE button, then from scratchcard, it has to take the user to beceexamlist. If the user tapped WASCE button at examtype then from scratchcard it has to take the user to wasceexamlist. Thank you very much indeed.